# Avoiding onCreate on parent stack without changing manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, oncreate

Changes to the manifest can be used to prevent onCreate from configuration change (like rotation).

But what about in this case:

- Activity A launches Activity B using `startActivity(intent)`
- Activity B goes through a configuration change (e.g. orientation change)
- Activity B is forced to `onCreate` again
- When returning to Activity A, it is also forced to `onCreate`

How can we prevent Activity A from being forced to onCreate when returning to it without changing the manifest for A? Is there an intent flag that we can use?

Comment: If your stack is A -> B and you finish B to be left with only A you will not get a call to A's `onCreate` as it was already called. You would get a call to `onStart` (if B completely covers A) followed by a call to `onResume`. The only way A's `onCreate` would be called would be if it was a new activity or you never actually launched A previously such as when using `TaskStackBuilder` https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Comment: @Bobbake4 No that's not the case. If I do not rotate the phone or otherwise cause a configuration change, then B finishes and A restarts. If I do rotate B, then A is created again

Comment: O I see, I will post an answer for your situation.

Comment: @Bobbake4 A's `onCreate` will also be called if your stack is A -> B and the app is killed in the background and later resumed.  In that case, B will be recreated, but A will not be recreated until you navigate back.

Comment: Good call @KevinKrumwiede, Activity lifecycles... Ahh

Comment: OP: Why don't you want to change the manifest?  And why do you want to prevent the recreation of A in the first place?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Activity A onCreate calls B to do some check, then B finishes and A continues. Even if A restarts then the check is done. Whereas if A is onCreated again, B is started again and the check is done twice+

Comment: @Lobstw Could you check if the bundle passed in to `onCreate` is null and if it is perform your check and if it's not null skip the check?

Comment: @Bobbake4 that seems like an answer to my issue. Will the bundle always have a non-null value in the case I described in the post? Is the bundle only null when it is first being onCreate?

Comment: I believe so yes, taking a look at the docs around `onCreate` it should only be non null if it's being re-intialized such as when a configuration change occurs or, like @KevinKrumwiede pointed out, if the app is killed in the background and Android is attempting to restore the state.